# SharePoint 2010 Manage Content And Structure Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After upgrading from sharepoint 2007 to 2010, our "manage content and structure" feature has stopped working.  The error says there is a field that is not properly installed in a list.  It says I need to go into the list settings and delete that field.  Problem is I have no clue which of the hundreds of lists is the issue.  We have deleted many old lists that had problems.  I have physically clicked on every list I could find to try to determine which list is causing the issue but have not been able to locate the problem child.  Does anyone know how I might go about finding the problem list so we can get our "Manage Content and Structure" section working again?

Actual Error Text:

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.

UPDATE:

06/22/2011 10:14:09.14  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://nova:80/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx?Source=%2F%5Flayouts%2Fviewlsts%2Easpx)  a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

06/22/2011 10:14:09.14  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Site=/  a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

06/22/2011 10:14:09.18  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   General xxpm    High    Unable to execute query: Error 0x81020014   a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

06/22/2011 10:14:09.18  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   General 8kh7    High    One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.    a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

06/22/2011 10:14:09.18  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName, String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView) a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

06/22/2011 10:14:09.18  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   General 90hv    Unexpected  Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object.  Please close SPWeb objects when you are done with all objects obtained from them, but not before.  Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRegionalSettings.get_GlobalInstalledLanguages()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.ThemingLocations.GetThemableStylesFolders(SPSite site, Boolean includeFileSystem)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssRegistrationRecord.UpdateThemableReferences(SPSite site, IEnumerable`1 references)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CssLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP._layouts_error_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)     at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(String message, String linkText, String linkUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorHandler(HttpApplication app, Boolean errorIsOnErrorPage)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.ErrorAppHandler(Object oSender, EventArgs ea)     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)   a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

06/22/2011 10:14:09.19  w3wp.exe (0x0ABC)   0x0308  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://nova:80/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx?Source=%2F%5Flayouts%2Fviewlsts%2Easpx)). Execution Time=51.3515051261099    a3b56f0a-13fc-4e2b-9ed0-3ce9c1ee4177

Answer (score 0):

Check the log file in 12\LOGS hive.

Comment: I have looked through these before and they aren't much help.  Here are the logs in case you notice something I did not.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Set the logging level to Verbose for SharePoint foundation category